# How to delete _$folder$ files from S3 with cmd or s3ncmd?

Tags: file-io, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, directory

I was using S3Fox and I end up with creating lots of _$folder$ files in multiple S3 directories. I want to clean them all. But the files are neither visible through  command line tool nor through S3Fox. They are only visible through AWS S3 console.
I am looking for solution something like

**hadoop fs -rmr s3://s3_bucket/dir1/dir2/dir3/*/*/*_\$folder\$**

Comment: Thanks,
I have mentioned the code solution here :
http://databuzzprd.blogspot.in/2013/10/how-to-delete-folder-file-from-aws-s3.html

Answer (score 2):

you can use s3cmd (http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) and the power of shell.

s3cmd del $(s3cmd ls s3://your-bucket | grep _$folder$ | awk '{ print $1}')